# PHP soapClient and Sequences issue

Tags: php, soap

I read through a few of the other solutions on here for issues that seemed similar to the problem that I am having, but none seemed to work.  Anyways I need to call a soap function that has a sequence of elements with the same name as their parent element, and the names all have a '.' in them.  Below is the part of the wsdl that I cant seem to wrap my head around a way of creating an array that will resemble what is needed.

Also, the sub array of 'option.list' is always going to have a different number of occurrences, so I need to somhow build this with a loop of some sort in php.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="option.list">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="cmn:ArrayType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="option.list">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="cmn:StructureType">
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SubItemId" nillable="true" type="cmn:DecimalType"/>
                                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SubOptions" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType"/>
                                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SubItemName" nillable="true" type="cmn:StringType"/>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

An idea of what I tried:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($options);$i++)
{
    $option_list[] = array(
      "option.list" => array(
      "SubItemId" => $i,
      "SubOptions" => $options[$i]['suboptions'],
      "SubItemName" => $options[$i]['subitemname']
      )
);
}

$instance = array(
    "option.list"=>$option_list
);
```

When I debug the request, it keeps showing this is what I am sending:

```
<ns1:option.list><ns1:option.list/></ns1:option.list>
```

Also, this is what the option.list array looks like when I print_r before I send it, if this helps at all.

```
                [option.list] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [option.list] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [SubItemId] => 0
                                        [SubOptions] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><form><select id="DBMS" label="DBMS type:" style="combo">MS SQL<option label="" /><option id="0" label="DB2">DB2</option><option id="1" label="IMS">IMS</option><option id="2" label="MS SQL">MS SQL</option><option id="3" label="Oracle">Oracle</option><option id="4" label="UDB">UDB</option></select><select id="Type" label="lation Type:" style="combo">Add New Instance<option label="" /><option id="0" label="Add New Environment">Add New Environment</option><option id="1" label="Add New Instance">Add New Instance</option><option id="2" label="Add New Database">Add New Database</option><option id="3" label="Modify Environment">Modify Environment</option><option id="4" label="Modify Instance">Modify Instance</option><option id="5" label="Modify Database">Modify Database</option><option id="6" label="Retire Environment">Retire Environment</option><option id="7" label="Retire Instance">Retire Instance</option><option id="8" label="Retire Database">Retire Database</option></select><select id="Complexity" label="xity:" style="combo">Complex [+$2500.00]<option label="" /><option id="0" label="Simple [+$500.00]">Simple [+$500.00]</option><option id="1" label="Medium [+$1000.00]">Medium [+$1000.00]</option><option id="2" label="Complex [+$2500.00]">Complex [+$2500.00]</option></select><select id="RecoveryTier" label="rability Tier:" style="combo">Tier 2<option label="" /><option id="0" label="Tier 1">Tier 1</option><option id="1" label="Tier 2">Tier 2</option><option id="2" label="Tier 3">Tier 3</option></select><select id="Backup" label=" Backup Required?" style="combo">Yes<option label="" /><option id="0" label="Yes">Yes</option><option id="1" label="No">No</option></select><select id="Replication" label=" tables require replication?" style="combo">UDB Dprop<option label="" /><option id="0" label="UDB Dprop">UDB Dprop</option><option id="1" label="Goldengate">Goldengate</option><option id="2" label="ASM">ASM</option><option id="3" label="No">No</option></select></form>
                                        [SubItemName] => DB Modification
                                    )

                            )

                    )
```

Comment: here is a snippet of the last thing I tried.... cant add it in this comment.. editing my original post now.

Comment: _it keeps showing this is what I am sending_ - is what you are sending what you intend to send? Would you include the code that calls SoapClient?

Comment: Nope that is not what I am expecting, what it is supposed to be sending is <ns2:option.list><ns2:option.list><ns2:SubItemId>0</ns2:SubItemId><ns2:SubOptions>escaped xml here</ns2:SubOptions><ns2:SubItemName>DB Modification</ns2:SubItemName></ns2:option.list></ns2:option.list>

Comment: anyone have any ideas of simply how to create an object that will translate into something like this:  <ns2:option.list><ns2:option.list><ns2:SubItemId>0</ns2:SubItemId><ns2:SubOption‌​s>escaped xml here</ns2:SubOptions><ns2:SubItemName>DB Modification</ns2:SubItemName></ns2:option.list></ns2:option.list>

Comment: I've faced sth like that. So far, the only way worked for me was to extend `SoapClient`, than override `__soapCall` and adjust the XML request (i.e.: some str replace etc.) before the `__doRequest`. In addition, take a look at `SoapVar` and `SoapParam` -- they almost make me get rid to this workaround. As soon as I figure out how to overcome this completely, I can post a final answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up having to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was never actually able to figure out how to get the desired soapEnvelope from an object or array.  But as a functional workaround, I was able to subclass SoapClient and override the __doRequest method.  This allowed me to send my own raw xml request which is now working.

I found this workaround here: [Sending Raw XML via PHP SoapClient request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608314/sending-raw-xml-via-php-soapclient-request)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following code but I didn't try:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($options);$i++) {
    $option_list[] = array(
       "SubItemId" => $i,
       "SubOptions" => $options[$i]['suboptions'],
       "SubItemName" => $options[$i]['subitemname']
    )
}

$instance = array(
    "option.list"=>$option_list
);
```

I think you needn't to make a parent array having a key 'option.list'.
The name 'option.list' is just for the wsdl type reference itself but is not sent at all.
The wsdl just tells you: 'option.list' type is a cardinal array of an associative array:

```
array(
    array(
        'SubItemId' => <DECIMAL>,
        'SubOptions' => '<STRING>',
        'SubItemName' => '<STRING>'
    ),
    array(
        'SubItemId' => <DECIMAL>,
        'SubOptions' => '<STRING>',
        'SubItemName' => '<STRING>'
    ),
    array(
        'SubItemId' => <DECIMAL>,
        'SubOptions' => '<STRING>',
        'SubItemName' => '<STRING>'
    ),
    ...,
    ...
)
```